# Google sheets unique multiple columns and output multiple columns

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, unique

I need some help working through this problem. I have multiple columns of data and I want to make it so that I only keep unique values and return the items to their respective columns.

```
1 2 3 6
1 1 4 7  
2 3 5 8
```

would end up like this:

```
1 3 4 6
2   5 7
      8
```

Right now I can do with one column using the `=unique()` function but I want to be able to put a new column of data and it would only spit out the unique items from that into the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet5");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet6");
var info = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var seen = {}; // make object acts as a hash table
var data = info; // make array same size as original array that has the entire sheet

for (var x = 0; x < info[x].length; x++){
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        if (!(info[i][x] in seen)) { // if item is not in seen
            data[i][x] = info[i][x]; // put item in location
            seen[data[i][x]] = true;}
        else {
           data[i][x] = "";}}} // if its not then add blank item to array
```

The previous answer had a join limit of 50,000 characters, so it had its own limit. this option helps for bigger sets of data. I think it could be tweaked still and improved

Comment: Neat piece of code. Yes, you are right that my answer (and others based on the split/join pattern) would be limited by the max length of string in a single cell. Something I have learnt in looking at your answer is that arrays in JavaScript are associative (not necessarily implemented as hash tables) so unlike with say Java you could use any data type as the 'subscript' of the array and not just integers.

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt at doing it with an array formula: assumes cells do not contain negative numbers, commas or pipe symbols.

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(transpose(split(join(",",text(unique(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,{transpose(A1:D3),-transpose(column(A1:D3))}),","))),"0;|")),"|")),",")))
```

[image]

Also works with full-column references

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(transpose(split(join(",",text(unique(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,{transpose(A:D),-transpose(column(A:D))}),","))),"0;|")),"|")),",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Paste these scripts in the script editor.

```js
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Show uniques', 'onlyShowUniques')
        .addToUi()
}

function onlyShowUniques() {
    var r, d, u, t, row, i, j;
    r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
    d = transpose(r.getValues());
    u = [];
    t = [];
    for (var i = 0, rl = d.length; i < rl; i++) {
        row = []
        for (var j = 0, cl = d[0].length; j < cl; j++) {
            if (d[i][j] && (!~u.indexOf(d[i][j]) || i == 0 && j == 0)) {
                u.push(d[i][j])
                row.push(d[i][j])
            } else {
                row.push(null)
            }
            row.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a === null) - (b === null) || +(a > b) || -(a < b);
            })
        }
        t.push(row)
    }
    r.setValues(transpose(t))
}

function transpose(array) {
    return Object.keys(array[0])
        .map(function (col) {
            return array.map(function (row) {
                return row[col];
            });
        });
}
```

2. Reopen the spreadsheet and see if an extra menu-item ('My Menu') is created.
3. Select the range you want to clear of duplicates.
4. Go to the menu item and select 'Show uniques'.
5. See if that brings about the expected output.